# Access static resource image in lightning markup img tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, static-resources

I have done my research on this and the solution is not working for me. Quick problem statement.

1. I have `Myresource` that is uploaded as static resource.
2. I am trying to access images under this in `img` tag as below.

> ```
> <img src="{!$Resource.Myresource+ '/images/closeIcon.png'}" alt="closeIcon" class="closeIcon" onclick="{!c.closeErrMsg}"></img>
> ```

but with no luck this is what I see on rendered img tag src attribute

```
src = "resource/1491989389000/VRResources/images/closeIcon.png"
```

Any idea guys? any heads up?

Thanks,
Guesta